# MS Access 2007 SQL with WHERE and GROUP BY does not use FILTER properly

Tags: sql, group-by, ms-access-2007, where-clause

I have a query that looks like this as SQL:

```
SELECT a,b,c
  FROM tableA
 WHERE d = "something"
 GROUP BY a,b,c
```

The query by itself works just fine.

When use the query in a report, it works fine.

If I try to apply a filter like

```
d="something" and e="whatever"
```

to the record source for the report in the report's OnActivate event, it prompts for a value for "e" and does not select anything, even if I enter "whatever" at the prompt for "e".

My understanding was that the "filter" is just the WHERE clause of the query, but it would appear that in the case of a TOTALs query (i.e. containing a GROUP BY clause), it is more like the HAVING clause. Is that what's going on? Is there any way around it?

---

To answer my second question, I got around it by building the entire SELECT statement in the report's OnOpen event and then used it to set the RecordSource. However, I would still like to understand how the filter works when there's a GROUP BY clause in the SELECT statement.

Comment: Are you sure the condition meets? try `OR` condition instead like `d="something" or e="whatever"`

Comment: I'm sure. In the OnActivate event, I used debug.print to show the actual RecordSource and Filter and when I use those values directly in the query, it works fine, i.e. selects records.

Answer (score 1):

The Filter property of the Report sees only the end result of the query, not the base table(s) of it.  So while you can use column d in your WHERE clause within the query (or any of the columns of your base table, for that matter), it is not projected the SELECT statement, so you can't refer to columns d or e on the Report filter.  To be honest, I'm not sure you can do what you want to do here like this, which is affect the pre-aggreation criteria in the query.